# "Something won't happen because something is good." It seems the 'something is good' would affect the first 'Something' negatively but doesn't

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, sentence-meaning

I am writing about minimal web design, and these are the first lines I wrote:

**Minimalism was one of the major web design trends throughout the 2010s. And it likely won't fade away in the 2020s because it's a fundamentally solid concept.**

I want to say 'minimalism won't go away because minimalism is a good concept to build websites upon.' The way I've written my sentence, it seems I am saying, 'Minimalism is a fundamentally solid concept, but that won't affect its popularity.' Or am I reading it wrong, and the sentences are perfectly alright for communicating the message I want to communicate?

Comment: Your sentences look fine to me to express the meaning you intend. The fact that it is a 'solid concept' is the reason why you think it won't fade away.

Comment: @KateBunting, thanks for your response :) I'll keep it as it is then.

Comment: Though the word *alright* gets a pass for being common, it's no different from *all right*, the original form. And starting your second sentence with *And* already startles the reader. Only *already* and *altogether* are solid for their distinct meanings from 'all ready' and 'all together'.